# Did any "washouts" of the Mercury program eventually become astronauts?

Tags: astronauts, project-mercury

The movie *The Right Stuff* portrays several dozen candidates for Project Mercury, who are eventually culled down to the final seven astronauts.

Did any of the unsuccessful candidates for the Mercury program eventually become astronauts?

Comment: Now that Edward Givens was added to the answer below, the answer is now complete and I have accepted it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To my knowledge, **only two** of the candidates that failed the tests did later become astronauts and flew on missions for NASA:

- **[Jim Lovell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Lovell)** 

   
  According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Mercury#Selection_and_training) on Project Mercury:

  > Navy Lt (later Capt) [Jim Lovell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Lovell), who was later an astronaut in the [Gemini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Gemini) and [Apollo programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_program), did not pass the physical tests.

  Lovell flew on 4 different missions, notably as the commander of the famous [Apollo 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_13). He was also part of the crew for Gemini 7 (Pilot) & 12 (Command Pilot) and Apollo 8 (Command Module Pilot).
- **[Pete Conrad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pete_Conrad#Aviation_career_in_the_U.S._Navy)** 

  Conrad, who also took part in the selection process, disagreed with the tests practiced by NASA and chose to voluntarily fail several of them.

  > Unlike his fellow candidates, Conrad rebelled against the regimen. During a Rorschach inkblot test, he told the psychiatrist that one blot card revealed a sexual encounter complete with lurid detail. When shown a blank card, he turned it around, pushed it back and replied, "It's upside down".
  >   
  >   Then when he was asked to deliver a stool sample to the onsite lab, he placed it in a gift box and tied a red ribbon around it. Eventually, he decided that he had had enough. After dropping his full enema bag on the desk of the clinic's commanding officer, he walked out. His initial application to NASA was denied with the notation *not suitable for long-duration flight*.

  He later reapplied and finally joined NASA in 1962. Conrad also flew on 4 different missions : Gemini 5 (Pilot) & 11 (Command Pilot), Apollo 12 (Commander) and [Skylab 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylab_2) (Commander)

**Bonus:** 
[Edward Givens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Givens), part of the finalists, did also become a NASA astronaut in 1966 but never actually flew on any mission as he unfortunately died in a car accident the following year.

> Givens had been a Project Mercury finalist back in 1959, and was one of nineteen astronauts selected by NASA in April 1966 for its [fifth astronaut group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Astronaut_Group_5). After completing basic astronaut training, he was assigned to the Apollo program and briefly served on the support crew for the first manned mission after the Apollo 1 fire, Apollo 7.

Comment: Also Pete Conrad.

Comment: Conrad kinda failed the tests "on purpose" (particularly the Rorschach test) so I wasn't sure if I could include him or not.

Comment: You could explain what happened in your answer.

Comment: "_not suitable for long-duration flight_" My first reaction (and probably one of the reasons I'm not an astronaut selector) is that he sounds ideal for long-duration flights to lighten the mood!

Comment: @TripeHound I guess NASA is looking for people instead who can work on long duration flights without someone lightening the mood. In the end there are still millions of dollars and at least a few lives invested in each flight, so any disobedience has the potential to spell doom not only on that specific mission but future ones as well.

Comment: @zovits guess you missed the bit where he later flew four missions for NASA...

Comment: @AaronF Good guess, but I did not. I think either NASA has loosened their selection process or Pete changed his attitude inbetween. Or both.

Comment: " This time, Conrad found the medical tests less invasive, and in June 1962 he was selected to join NASA.[4]" .. sounds like the former.

Comment: Pete Conrad sounds like the inspiration for Mark Watney.

Comment: @Skyler Funny, I was going to say he reminded me of Jack O'Neill as portrayed by Richard Dean Anderson.

Answer (score 7):

He was not exactly a Mercury washout, but [Deke Slayton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deke_Slayton) was selected as one of the original Mercury 7, and was scheduled to take the fourth Mercury flight (second orbital, following John Glenn) but was grounded due to a heart condition. He famously went on to become chief of the astronaut office, being responsible for crew selection throughout Gemini and Apollo.

After spending several years focusing on his health, his atrial fibrillations cleared up. He was medically cleared for flight in 1972, too late for the Apollo moon landings, but he assigned himself to the crew of the [Apollo-Soyuz Test Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo%E2%80%93Soyuz_Test_Project) in 1975 -- his one and only space flight.